# Prove that for all $g$ continuous functions, with $g(0) = g(1) = 1$ and $\int f(x)g(x)dx = 0$ then $f(x) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I am trying to prove that if $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function for which the following is true: for all continuous functions $g:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ with $g(0) = g(1) = 1$, with $\int_0^1f(t)g(t)dt = 0$ then $f(x) = 0, \forall x \in [0,1]$. Any ideas on how I can approach this? I have tried playing around with g(x), and also tried approaching it more theoretically, starting by supposing that $f(x) \neq 0$ but both without much success. The problem is from a university exam on Calculus 1, where integrals are studied on a basic level (Riemann integrals, Integration techniques and basic theorems for Intergrals)  . Thanks for any help!

Comment: I guess you wish to either use $[a, b]$ everywhere or $[0, 1]$ everywhere.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it!

Comment: Great! Also, consider adding some details of your own. What have you tried? Where did you encounter this problem (what theorems have you seen that led up to this?)? This helps us know at what level we can answer your question. For example, this reminds me of Weierstrass' approximation theorem. Have you seen that?

Comment: @average_discrete_math_enjoyer Are you sure this is true? Take $$g(x) =
  \begin{cases}
                                   -4x + 1 & \text{if $0 \leq x < 0.5$} \\
                                   4x - 3 & \text{if $0.5 \leq x \leq 1$} 
  \end{cases}$$
Here $g$ is continuous but $f(x) =1$ also satisfies your condition.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations! I tried to write as much as I know about the problem, and I hope it helps! Also I have not heard about the Weierstrass' approximation theorem unfortunately.

Comment: @bigbang Well I am asked to prove it on a test, so I guess it holds? I am not sure however, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @bigbang: The question says that if $\int_0^1 fg = 0$ for _all_ continuous $g$ with $g(0) = g(1) = 1$, then $f \equiv 0$. In your example, the integral is $0$ only for one $g$.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani oh alright, thanks, I misinterpreted the question. Anyhow, I won't delete the comment, just in case for people to see the possible misunderstandings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sketch.**

1. From the given hypothesis, deduce that the following is true as well: Given any continuous function $h$ with $h(0) = h(1) = 0$, we have $$\int_0^1 f(t)h(t)\ {\mathrm d}t = 0.$$
   (Hint: Write $h = (h + 1) - 1$.)
2. Assume $f$ is not identically $0$. Wlog, $f > 0$ at some point.
   Use continuity to conclude that there exists $\delta > 0$ and some interval $(a, b) \subset (0, 1)$ such that $f(x) > \delta$ for all $x \in (a, b)$.
3. Define a continuous function $h$ on $[0, 1]$ which has the property that $h = 0$ outside $(a, b)$ and $h = 1$ on some subinterval $[c, d] \subset (a, b)$. (Try to find an $h$ with a "trapezoidal graph".)
4. Show that $\int_0^1 fh > 0$. This is contradiction since $h$ is continuous and satisfies $h(0) = h(1) = 0$.

Comment: Well let's suppose that indeed there exists an $x_0$ such that $f(x_0) > 0$, then from continuity I can get that $f(x) > f(x_0)/2 > 0 $ for all x in $(x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta)$ (if I set ε = $\frac{f(x_0)}{2}$ . What If I set g(x) to be 0 for the interval $[a, x_0 - \delta]$ and $[x_0 + \delta, 1]$ but then set $g(x_0) = f(x_0)$ ? Then can't I get that $0 = \int^1_0 f(x)g(x)dx = \int^{x_0 + \delta}_{x_0 - \delta} $, but for this to be true then we have to have $f(x)g(x) = 0$ and therefore $f(x_0)g(x_0) = 0 = f^2(x_0)$ which is a contradiction with $f(x_0) > 0$? Could this work?

Comment: Your idea for point 2. is correct. You just need to be a bit careful that you pick $x_0$ which is not $0$ or $1$ (continuity will again let you do this). Your definition of $g$ is not complete, though. You have only defined $g$ on $[0, x_0 - \delta] \cup \{x_0\} \cup [x_0 + \delta, 1]$. You need to define it on $(x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta) \setminus \{x_0\}$ as well. Moreover, you need to define it so that it is continuous. I don't quite understand how you are computing the integral either.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to fix these. Your way seems pretty cool but finding that $g$ might be my problem again, I'll try to look into it again though.

Comment: @average_discrete_math_enjoyer: Try the following: (With notations as in my answer) Define $g$ to be $0$ on $[0, a)$. Then, on $[a, c]$, define it to be a linear function such that $g(a) = 0$  and $g(c) = 1$. Then, define it to be $1$ on $(c, d)$. Again, on $[d, b]$, make it linear with $g(d) = 1$ and $g(b) = 0$. Finally, define it to be $0$ on $(b, 1]$.

Comment: I think I did something! I tried to basically find the line passing through the points! For example, I set a point A  to be A = (x = α, y =0) (where α is a parameter, and A denotes the point with y = 0, and $x$ equal to the value of a ) and a point B to be B = (x = γ, y = 1). (where again γ is a parameter), and I found the equation for the line passing through these points. That way, I get the linearity on $[a,c]$ in a such a way so $g(a) = 0$ and $g(c) = 1$. So I ended up with $f(x) = \frac{1}{γ-α}x + \frac{α}{α-γ}$, for $x \in [a,c]$. So if I do the same thing for [d,b] I am done right?

Comment: Yes, the function $g(x) = \frac{x - a}{c - a}$ for $x \in [a, c]$ is what I had in mind. Similarly for $[d, b]$. With this, you are done with the construction of $g$. You still have to justify that $\int_0^1 fg > 0$.

Comment: Of course, but that step doesn't seem so difficult, I think we have done like 90% of the job up to that point.